# How a method can declare a string and have it automatically filled with information

Tags: c#

The following is a simple program that takes an input string, reverses the order of the characters and prints the result.

There are two methods here (//method 1 and //method 2) that both produce the same result. I am just utterly lost in how they do this.

```
namespace HelperMethods
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("The Name Game");

        Console.Write("What's your first name? ");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("What's your last name? ");
        string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("In what city were you born? ");
        string city = Console.ReadLine();

        DisplayResult(
            ReverseString(firstName),
            ReverseString(lastName),
            ReverseString(city));

        Console.WriteLine();

        DisplayResult(
            ReverseString(firstName) + " " +
            ReverseString(lastName) + " " +
            ReverseString(city));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //accepts input peramaters variable = string name = message 
    private static string ReverseString(string message) 
        {//inputs characters, concatenates and returns string
        char[] messageArray = message.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(messageArray);
        return String.Concat(messageArray); 
        }

    private static void DisplayResult( //method 1
        string reversedFirstName, 
        string reversedLastName, 
        string reversedCity)
        {
        Console.Write("Results: ");
        Console.Write(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
            reversedFirstName,
            reversedLastName,
            reversedCity));
        }

    private static void DisplayResult(string message) //method 2
    {
        Console.Write("Results: ");
        Console.Write(message);
    }
}
}
```

how can you declare string reversedFirstName and have it filled with the string?

Comment: The data is being reversed and sent as a parameter to method1, and reversed and built into a single string for method2.

Comment: First the arguments are executed and then the static display method is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it might give you insight with this code: broken down into parts

```
String revFirst = ReverseString(firstName); // get reverse of firstName
String revLast = ReverseString(lastName); // get reverse of lastName
String revCity = ReverseString(city); // get reverse of city

// use string format to combine the reversed strings creating a new one
String mystring = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", revFirst, revLast, revCity);
DisplayResult(mystring); // now display that new string using method 2
```

Note that the net result of `mystring` is the same as combining the strings manually as is done calling the other method, with the `ReverseString(firstName) + " " + ...` code

Comment: @AnılYalçın #iamverysmart

Comment: Thanks Mark Schultheiss. I guess what was tripping me up was that the methods were written below the main body of code.